# VB.NET PUT Request with --data-binary won't work. Works in curl. 401 Unauthorized

Tags: vb.net, api, curl, put

I've got a bit of a problem and I'm struggling with this on. I'm trying to be able to upload audio to an online service through their API.

I have a curl command that works, but it doesn't work in VB.net (Community 2017 if it helps). I know that MS are going away from VB, but I was wanting to incorporate this new upload feature in to a current program I'd written over the years.

The problem is that this example for curl works: (Usually you would have a programId, clipID and an Auth API key (SPECIALLONGKEY) as well, but I hid those)

```
    curl "https://api.omnystudio.com/v0/programs/{programId}/clips/{clipId}/audio" --request PUT --data-binary "@birthday.mp3" --header "Accept:application/json" --header "Authorization:OmnyToken SPECIALLONGKEY"
```

Yet, when I try the same thing in VB.NET I get a "401 Unauthorized" response.

```
    Dim httpClient As New Http.HttpClient()
    Dim request = New Http.HttpRequestMessage(New Http.HttpMethod("PUT"), "https://api.omnystudio.com/v0/programs/{programId}/clips/{clipId}/audio")
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encording", "gzip, deflate, br")
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OmnyToken SPECIALLONGKEY")

    request.Content = New StringContent("C:\test\birthday.mp3")
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    Dim response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result

    Debug.Print(request.ToString)
    Debug.Print(response.ToString)
```

I get this response like this:

```
Method: PUT, RequestUri: 'https://api.omnystudio.com/v0/programs/{programId}/clips/{clipId}/audio', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Accept-Encording: gzip, deflate, br
  Authorization: OmnyToken SPECIALLONGKEY
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Content-Length: 50
}
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized. Provide a valid Authentication header', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
  Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
  CF-RAY: 5841cc895a0fda5e-SYD
  Cache-Control: no-cache, private
  Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2020 01:12:34 GMT
  Server: cloudflare
  WWW-Authenticate: OmnyToken
  Content-Length: 0
}
```

The API documentation doesn't help me much, as it just says: "The clip's audio can either be provided as a binary request body"

I ran Fiddler to see what is happening and it all seems to check out fine with the correct headers being send etc. Just wondering if or what I'm doing wrong, or, if I should just go the way of writing batch files, and then have the program execute them each time this specific occurrence needs to happen. Thanks.

Comment: I have an update from the devs, and will update this when (if) I get it working, for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a little help with this from the developers, it seems there were 2 problems.
The biggest was (and still is) a redirect problem, which is still happening, but the audio is now uploading, as there was a ContentType problem.

While the redirect still happens, this can be overcome by polling the API for when a the upload of the clip did or didn't work, and when it's finished processing.

Here's the updated vb.net sample code:

```
    Dim OmnyProgramId As String = ""
    Dim OmnyClipId As String = ""
    Dim OmnyToken As String = "SPECIALLONGKEY"

    ' This creates a 303 "See Other" Error
    Dim myHandler As HttpClientHandler = New HttpClientHandler()
    myHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    Dim httpClient As New Http.HttpClient(myHandler)

    ' Original
    ' This creates a redirect 303 "StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized. Provide a valid Authentication header" Error
    'Dim httpClient As New Http.HttpClient() 

    Dim request = New Http.HttpRequestMessage(New Http.HttpMethod("PUT"), "https://api.omnystudio.com/v0/programs/" & OmnyProgramId & "/clips/" & OmnyClipId & "/audio")
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encording", "gzip, deflate, br")
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OmnyToken " & OmnyToken)

    'easily swap between two test files.
    'Dim filename As String = "C:\test\bahamas.mp3"
    Dim filename As String = "C:\test\birthday.mp3"

    Dim dataBytes() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename)
    Dim dataStream = New MemoryStream(dataBytes)
    request.Content = New StreamContent(dataStream)

    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("audio/mpeg")

    ' Do the upload
    Dim response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result

    ' See the output
    Debug.Print("::")
    Debug.Print(request.ToString)
    Debug.Print("::")
    Debug.Print(response.ToString)
```

I'm still getting header responses that are difficult to respond to, the audio at least uploads. 
These are the header responses: (once again program, clips and api key are censored)

```
::
Method: PUT, RequestUri: 'https://api.omnystudio.com/v0/programs/{program}/clips/{clip}/audio', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Accept-Encording: gzip, deflate, br
  Authorization: OmnyToken SPECIALLONGKEY
  Content-Type: audio/mpeg
  Content-Length: 1392706
}
::
StatusCode: 303, ReasonPhrase: 'See Other', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-RateLimit-Limit: 10
  X-RateLimit-Remaining: 9
  X-RateLimit-Reset: 10
  CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
  Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
  CF-RAY: 58436ad7eec8fd2e-SYD
  Cache-Control: no-cache, private
  Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2020 05:55:26 GMT
  Location: https://api.omnystudio.com/v0/programs/{program}/clips/{clip}
  Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d5d4e3ab37736930123; expires=Fri, 15-May-20 05:55:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.omnystudio.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
  Server: cloudflare
  Content-Length: 0
}
```

I hope this helps someone, considering nearly everything is in C#.NET these days, and VB.NET examples are going the way of the dodo.